# Figuring out the base URL where JS script was loaded from within a script

Tags: javascript, html

Assume that I have a JS script included into my HTML page http://app.example.com:

```
<script src="http://app.foo.com/script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://app.bar.com/script.js"></script>
```

which is the same version of JS, but served from different domains.
Actually it's the same script that wants to know where it was loaded from.

So basically I want script.js having the code:

```
// 'app.foo.com' or 'app.bar.com' returned depending where it was loaded from
let baseUrl = somehowGetTheBaseUrlWhereImHostedAt();
```

P.S. Actually the problem I'm trying to solve is that the JS script would load (insert into DOM) an iframe from app.foo.com/iframe.html if it comes from app.foo.com or app.bar.com/iframe.html if it comes from app.bar.com

Comment: Is the name of the file pre-determined and unique?

Comment: which file? iframe.html and script.js are unique across all enviroments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iframe.html and script.js are unique across all enviroments

Assuming that the `script.js` file name is pre-determined and unique, we can search for a script tag that imports the given script. Then fetch the full source url from the script tag.

**Note:** In the example below I am using jquery simply because its available in the SO sandbox.

```js
const fileName = 'jquery.min.js';

// src$="foo" is equivalent to "where the value of the src field ends with 'foo' "
const $script = document.querySelector(`script[src$="${fileName}"]`);
const scriptSrc = $script.src;

console.log(scriptSrc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: They could also add an ID to their SCRIPT tag, and just pull the path using the ID as a query selector. That would allow the file name not be set as a variable. Just an alternative solution.

Comment: @HBlackorby that assumes that OP is consuming the script. The consumer might be some other developer. In that case needing the script have an ID might be hard to convey.

Comment: @HBlackorby also, if you are to convince devs to add an ID to the script tag, then you might as well ask them to add a `data-origin` tag that tells the script where it was loaded from and bypass the issue entirely.

Comment: He said it was his HTML page, so I assume he wrote/can update the HTML. If not, then your solution works great too.

Comment: thanks guys, if that's the only solution (I was actually hoping for a more elegant one), then it's fine.